# Inserting a value into another value, Batch

Tags: variables, batch-file

So, let's say I have a value call **value** it's value is **hello goodbye**

Let's say I have another value called **value2** it's value is **there**

```
 set value=hello goodbye

 set value2=there
```

Is there anyway to put value2 into value, so that if echo'd it'd be printed out as **hello there goodbye**.

Comment: Batch?  What is batch? You don't know name of the language?

Comment: `Windows Command Shell Script Language` (WCSSL) aka `Batch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways:

To insert the string at a particular position:

```
set value=hello goodbye
set value2=there
set "value=%value:~0,5% %value2%%value:~6%"
```

To substitute the string for *every* space within the first variable:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set value=hello goodbye
set value2=there
set "value=!value: = %value2% !"
```

To break the string at the first space (or set of spaces), and insert the string:

```
set value=hello goodbye
set value2=there
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("%value%") do set "value=%%A %value2% %%B"
```

Comment: So we meet again, thanks for explaining how too place it in other places, whilst I did not ask I was wondering about that. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set value=hello goodbye
set value2=there

set value=!value: = %value2% !

echo %value%
```